# Endless Query Loop In Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

I will delete millions records from a table in mysql dbms, but i don't want to delete all records at one time not to force database server cpu. That's why i want to use my query many times. My whille loops doesn't work.I don't know why. How to do that? My query is below:

```
while 1=1 DO
delete  FROM customer.generallogs  where DateEnter < '2019-04-03 16:13:28' limit 100000;
end while;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP can be like (draft code):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteFromGeneralLogs (IN DeleteTill DATETIME)
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done:=1;
-- IF DeleteTill IS NULL THEN LEAVE;
WHILE done = 0 DO
    SELECT SLEEP(1) INTO done; -- small pause between chunks
    DELETE 
        FROM customer.generallogs  
        WHERE DateEnter < DeleteTill  
        LIMIT 100000;
END WHILE;
END;
```

And then

```
CALL DeleteFromGeneralLogs('2019-04-03 16:13:28');
```

Comment: @Omer Pay attention to commented line which checks input parameter... uncomment it and make more strong condition - simple error/misprint in it can cause actual data damage. And I'd recommend to add `ORDER BY DateEnter ASC` into DELETE query - of course, it decreases speed, but decreases the problems when the procedure is called errorneously or with wrong parameter, because it will delete the most old records first.